# Get cookie value in jsp

Tags: java, cookies

on my Java servlet I've initialized a cookie as below,

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
String loc = "/u/poolla/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/"+timeStamp;
Cookie thecookie = new Cookie("thecookie", loc);
thecookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
response.addCookie(thecookie);
```

and in cookie comments I've added some data as below,

```
thecookie.setComment(fileTxt);
```

Now on my jsp page when I try to access this comment it returned a null,

```
 <%
    Cookie my = null;
    my.getComment();%>
```

How do I get the comment value set in java to my jsp page??

Comment: How do you access the cookie in jsp file?

Comment: In general, I'll suggest to pass values from the controller and avoid scriptlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSP use,

```
<%
   Cookie cookie = null;
   Cookie[] cookies = null;
   cookies = request.getCookies();
    if( cookies != null)
      {
      for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
         cookie = cookies[i];
         String b = cookie.getComment();
     request.setAttribute("xyz", b);
     }
     }
%>
```

and then you can use is by `${xyz}` in htmls and use `b` if you want to use it in JSP code.

Comment: upvoting both of you just for the comaradarie shown in discussing and solving the problem at hand :)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `my` to `null` and accessing the comment. This will throw `NullPointerException` .Change your code to

```
    <%
    Cookie[] my = request.getCookies();
    for(int i=0;i<my.length;i++){
    String comment = my[i].getComment();
    out.println(comment);
    }
    %>
```

Note : Please **avoid** using [Scriptlets](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Top-5-reasons-that-JSP-scriptlets-suck). they are **NOT** recommended

Comment: I'll suggest to avoid scriptlets

Comment: it says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Cookie[] to Cookie`

Comment: This is a better answer to the point, I think this should have been accepted.

Comment: @Zedai OP has accepted your answer, since it has helped to solve the problem OP faced :) But, anyway thanks for the compliment!

Comment: upvoting both of you just for the comaradarie shown in discussing and solving the problem at hand :)

Answer (score 1):

**Cookie**: `cookie['cookie_name']`

**Cookie Value**: `cookie['cookie_name'].value`

Comment: Could you explain further? Maybe add some reference